# Trying to set different arrays depending on value. Error: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function

Tags: laravel, vue.js, element-ui

I'm trying to set this array to different thing depending on another value and get the error

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

I'm setting up the array as empty in the `data()` in the vue,

```
ranktexts: [],
```

and then in the methods i'm using this code

```
texts(rank) {
    if (rank === 3) {
        this.ranktexts = ['Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno'];
    } else if (rank === 4) {
        this.ranktexts = ['Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Excelente'];
    } else if (rank === 5) {
        this.ranktexts = ['Muy Mal', 'Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Excelente'];
    } else {
        this.ranktexts = ['Muy Mal', 'Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Muy Bueno', 'Excelente'];
    }
},
```

This is where I'm calling it

```
<div class="question_reply" v-if="form.response_type_id === 3">
    <el-form-item>
        <el-rate v-model="value"
            :max="form.rank"
            :texts="texts(form.rank)"
            show-text
            allow-half
        ></el-rate>
    </el-form-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Your component will be re-rendered infinitely.

When rendering, `:texts="texts(form.rank)"` to get the results you called a method with param.

In that method, you updated the `ranktexts` in the data. Updating `ranktexts` will make the component to re-render.

So rendering again.

> render -> texts(form.rank) -> updating ranktexts -> render

To solve this. I think there's no need to use `ranktexts`.

Just return array.

```
texts(rank) {
    if (rank === 3) {
       return ['Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno'];
    }
    if (rank === 4) {
       return ['Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Excelente'];
    }
    if (rank === 5) {
       return ['Muy Mal', 'Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Excelente'];
    }
    return ['Muy Mal', 'Mal', 'Indiferente', 'Bueno', 'Muy Bueno', 'Excelente'];
}
```

Comment: @Nancy Did you send prop like `show-text="true"`? If then just add `:` like `:show-text="true"`. If not, please provide some more codes in your question so I can help you.

Comment: Hi I figured it out, in the return I was doing `return 'true'` instead of just `return true`, thanks